# NSMutableData to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cryptography, nsstring, nsmutabledata

Hi everyone I'm working with symmetric encryption in my app to encrypt messages that users send to each other. Now I'm trying to create a fairly secure key to decrypt this data (decryption key) using an NSMutableData. Currently I have two questions:

1. Is a 256-bit key for decryption safe enough?
2. I have some problems with NSString. When I want to retrieve the string value of the NSMutableData my NSLog always returns me a null value

Where am I doing wrong?

```
NSMutableData *masterKey = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:32];
    int result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 32, masterKey.mutableBytes);
    if (result != noErr) {
        NSLog(FAILED_MASTERKEY);
        return;
    }
NSLog(@"MASTER %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:masterKey encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding]);
```

---

```
2018-11-28 16:06:31.803868+0100 [41860:9341804] MASTER (null)
```

Comment: Which Cryptographic algorithm in which mode you are using? The code you show doesn't contain any code about crypto? only [SecRandomCopyBytes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1399291-secrandomcopybytes) that is `Generates an array of cryptographically secure random bytes.` Also, you have two question that are not really realted.

Comment: @kelalaka For cryptography I'm using Themis an open source library https://github.com/cossacklabs/themis/wiki/Objective-C-Howto  .. This key is used for symmetric encryption for now.. How could I be clearer in my question? The fundamental problem is that I'm going to encrypt this 256bit key and then use it later as a decryption key for other data ...I'm sorry if I was not clear enough ... sometimes it's not easy to give a perfect explanation :(

Comment: @Rob   creating a random string with [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString] + base64 encoded + perceptual escape would be just as safe?

Comment: But which algorithms

Comment: @kelalaka EC algorithms

Comment: I'd suggest you split this into two separate questions. I've answered the "how do I create a string representation of an arbitrary binary value", as suggested by this question's title, below. But the encryption questions seem like a complete different issue.

Comment: Re `globallyUniqueString`, that would appear to ensure uniqueness, but I see nothing to suggest cryptographically robust randomness. I'd stick with cryptographic functions.

Comment: When you post your separate crypto question, I'd suggest you step back and give a broader context. This whole notion of generating a single encryption key seems suspect, introducing a problem of how do you share this between the various devices. I would have expected that you'd want to generate key pairs on each device and exchange public keys or something like that.

Comment: @Rob Yes, in fact my encryption will be asymmetric with the public key and the private key for each user ... I am using a master key that serves as an encryption key to decrypt the private key of the user .. The master key will be inside of Keychain .. That's why I was working on a solid key ..

Comment: You cannot just take some random data and say that's a EC encryption key, that's not how it works. You need to look into `SecKeyGeneratePair` function from `CommonCrypto` native framework, or find a good library for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create `NSString` directly from arbitrary binary data. Alternatives range from displaying hexadecimal representation (e.g. from the `description` method) or using some other text representation of binary data (e.g. base-64). But you can't just pass random binary data to `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`.

```
NSLog(@"Hex:     %@", [masterKey description]);
NSLog(@"Hex:     %@", masterKey);                                   // directly logging the `NSData` will also use its `description`
NSLog(@"Base 64: %@", [masterKey base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]);
```

The common technique for exchanging binary data via web service is base-64. But if the intent was merely to log the value so that you could see that, indeed, a value was generated, then just logging its `description` is simplest.